# Why a proper sinon.stub() is returned on the inner object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, chai

I need to stub a chained function:

```
io.in(param).emit(param);
```

To do so, I've created a stub like this:

```
sandbox.stub(io, 'in').returns({
      emit: sinon.stub(), 
    });
```

I've discovered that I can make assertions using:

```
io.in().emit
```

For example I can assert:

```
 sinon.assert.calledOnce(io.in().emit);
```

Why is this actually working? As for my knowledge, for every `io.in()` call a new object will be created that doesn't know anything about past stub records.

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `io.in()` might return a different object, but you've told `sinon` exactly what you want the stub to return for each call: the literal object:

```
{
  emit: sinon.stub(), 
}
```

You've passed that object to `return`, the argument to `return` is evaluated and then the function `return` is called with this argument. `return` doesn't need to be called again every time the stub is called. If you want *that* behavior, you can use `callsFake` and return the new object each time.

You can think of it working like:

```js
function returns(val){
  return () => val
}
function stub(){
  console.log("stub called")
  return () => "I'm a stubb"
}

let f  = returns({key: stub()})

// stubb only called once - even with two f() calls
// both calls to f() return idential objects
console.log(f() === f()) // same value on each call?
console.log(f()) // doesn't call stub again
```